# How to reply using sidebar in app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-workspace-add-ons

I have a Google app script application for gmail. From the sidebar, when I click a button, I want to be able to paste text into the current reply email where my cursor is. Based on the Google docs, there is no API for this. I am only seeing it is possible to create a completely new email draft. Anyone know how I can insert text into the current reply email by using the sidebar?

Comment: If it's possible, I believe you might be able do this with a Gmail Workspace Add-On but you would have to use the card service and not an html sidebar.

Comment: "Based on the Google docs, " What Google docs? Reply using the sidebar is possible, using the sidebar it's possible to edit a draft. See the note from this doc https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/gmail/composehttps://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/gmail/compose